# Flutter - Table / TableCell: How to set background color of one cell

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a table widget and I have to adjust the background color of one cell. So I put a `Container` widget in the `TableCell` widget and set its color. This works fine if all cells of that row have the same height (b1). However if the height of another cell is larger (b2), my approach fails as you can see in this image.

[image]

I understand that the height of the `Container` matches its child and not the height of its parent. But I could not come up with a better approach. Any ideas?

Here is the code I used for the table:

```
Table(
    border: TableBorder.symmetric(
        inside: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.grey600),
        outside: BorderSide.none
    ),
    children: [
        TableRow(
            children: [
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('a'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('b'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('c'))),
            ],
        ),
        TableRow(
            children: [
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('abc abc abc'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(color: Colors.grey[300], child: Text('b'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('c'))),
            ],
        ),
        TableRow(
            children: [
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('a'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('b'))),
                TableCell(child: Container(child: Text('c'))),
            ],
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill

```
TableCell(
  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill, 
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.grey[300], 
    child: Text('b')
  )
),
```

Comment: I just realized that TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill only works for a single cell. If it is applied to all cells in a row, the height of that row is set to 0 which is unfortunately a very undesired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration( Colors.blue),
```